# Reading HTML file from URL

Tags: php, html, shoutcast

While most of the time I'd just use `file_get_contents` and CURL, I can't get it to work with a port in the URL. How can I read this file? 
http://174.120.124.178:7800/7.html (It's a shoutcast statistics file)

Ultimately, I just want the text after the last comma.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It has nothing to do with the port.  They're blocking you because you're not using a browser user agent.  `curl` does let you fake the user agent, but that may be a violation of the site's terms of service.

According to [this post](http://forums.shoutcast.com/showpost.php?s=e59c95297b25b3f7a75debb480c11bab&p=1983467&postcount=4) it's not about blocking scripts, but just distinguishing between Shoutcast clients and everything else.  So the code is:

```
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla");
```

Comment: While this does solve the problem with my code, the ultimate issue is that my shared hosting account does not allow me to use CURL on ports other than 80 or 443.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to download your file with Curl on the command line and got a 404 error; it does load with Firefox and Lynx.  [This page](http://forums.winamp.com/showthread.php?t=156465) says that you need to change the `User-Agent` string for it to download.

Comment: Reading various forum posts, you just need a `User-Agent` header that contains `Mozilla` somewhere within it; see http://forums.shoutcast.com/showthread.php?t=147753.

Answer (score 0):

`CURLOPT_PORT` Needs to be set to the appropriate port perhaps~