# Order data gotten by fgets

Tags: php

So i have this  script right here to get data from shoutcast

```
$fp = @fsockopen("$host", $port, &$errno, &$errstr, 30);
fputs($fp,"GET /admin.cgi?pass=jkl&mode=viewxml HTTP/1.0\r\nUser-Agent: XML Getter (Mozilla Compatible)\r\n\r\n");
echo '<pre>';

while(!feof($fp)) {
    echo fgetss($fp);

}

fclose($fp);
```

Problem is that the data i get is all in one line.. if i try something like this

```
echo fgetss($fp) . '<BR>';
```

But it doesn't work..it just echos out 
 on the **HTTP/1.0 200 OK Content-Type:text/xml** lines..

I'd like if possible to put the data in an array so i can echo-it out nicely OR echo it out ,but also echo it with the xml thing which is in <> so i know what that value actually represents

This is the only method that works with shoutcast to get data.. so don't tell me to use curl because it just doesn't work..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reading HTML file from URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5136712/reading-html-file-from-url)

Answer (score 1):

First `<BR>` is not valid tag. It should be `<br />`. Second, if you want to display the content "by lines" you need to either wrap it in `<pre>` and `</pre>` tags (so you get line breaks from server response, or you need to to `str_replace("\r\n\", '<br />', $string);` (mind the quotes. it matters!)

Comment: +1. HTML tags should be lowercased. `<br>` is acceptable in HTML5, however.

Comment: I know. The other forms are there for compatibility with XHTML, but my mantra is "the less exceptions, the better", so I tend to use `<br />` everywhere :)

Comment: True! Your `str_replace` is broken fyi

Comment: I used pre..it doesn't work. I'll try your str_replace code and i'll be back.. (I'm used to use <BR>,it always worked..so idk,sometimes i use <br /> tho) 
Edit: Used your str_replace code,doesn't work.. the string is inline data.. so for example i have in a db this "id 1 name asd pass safe" and when i echo it out it is 1asdsafe ..